# How do I do a bot launch an excel file, enable editing and then close it after 10 minutes with python?

Tags: python, excel

**My task:** My bot needs to *launch an Excel file*, enable editing and close the excel file after 10 minutes.

*Extra note: My bot will to open an excel file with Python, enable editing and close after 10 minutes, just like we double click it with mouse. **I've search for a while, but seems all the pages are talking about how to read and write an excel file with code, but I'm not trying to do this.***

**So, is there any solution for my task?**

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO please see [ask] and [mcve] your question is very broad asking for an all encompassing solution where ask SO is for specific problems you've run into which are reproducible by others. You'll need to be specific and define what you mean by bot as well. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: You cannot open and interact with the program Excel itself through Python (or most other programming languages). You can modify excel files. VBA is commonly used to script Excel though I don't know if it is possible what you are asking for. It also makes little sense to me but I don't know what your use case is and what you exactly mean with your question.

Answer (score -1):

use win32 Com for opening excel file , click enable editing and close by using pyautogui module.

```
Pyautogui
```